# Windows Phone emulator "key not present" with Cordova Tools for Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to get started with the Multip-device Hybrid Apps (Cordova tools) for visual studio (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381).

---

The problem:

It builds and it deploys with the ripple emulator, but won't deploy to any other configuration.

---

The question:

Does anyone know what is causing these errors, how to fix them, or better ways to gather information on the problem? What I have discovered is below. Your consideration and/or help is much appreciated!

---

Error on windows phone:

Error   2   The given key was not present in the dictionary.    BlankCordovaApp1

---

Error for windows 8:

Error   2   Error : DEP1700 : The recipe file "C:\Users\sfarley\Desktop\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bin\Windows-x64\Debug\BlankCordovaApp1.build.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project.

---

Errors with android: (would post image but don't have the reputation points, sorry)

Error   3   process.chdir(path);    BlankCordovaApp1

Error   5   Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory    BlankCordovaApp1

Error   2   C:\Users\sfarley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js:47 BlankCordovaApp1

Error   12  at startup (node.js:119:16) BlankCordovaApp1

Error   8   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) BlankCordovaApp1

Error   6   at Object. (C:\Users\sfarley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js:47:13)  BlankCordovaApp1

Error   13  at node.js:902:3    BlankCordovaApp1

Error   9   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)   BlankCordovaApp1

Error   7   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)   BlankCordovaApp1

Error   11  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)   BlankCordovaApp1

Error   10  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) BlankCordovaApp1

Error   4   ^   BlankCordovaApp1

---

I have attempted to place loggers in the emulator.js file to see what path is the problem, but to no avail.

What I have tried:

- Re-installing the tools.
- Re-installing visual studio.
- Re-installing most of the tools it depends on (windows phone sdk, etc.)
- Installing on a clean VM.
- Putting console logs in their deployment js files.However they messages did not bubble up to the console.

Comment: .@farlee, could you post separately the outputs for Win8 and WP8, while deploying them to an emulator? The above logs are unclear.

Comment: .@farlee, please note that WP8 emulation requires hyper-v, which is not available on a VM - if you want to test WP8 emulation, you need to install the bits on a physical machine instead.

Comment: @Priyank, Thanks for the quick response! I have edited it. Good to know that it won't work on a VM. I tried an azure vm because it was the most convenient blank machine. Most of my efforts have been on a real machine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. This is because by default it has Android mobile selected and dropdown list to change devices doesn't present by default. Go here to add it to the tool bar,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2954109

Comment: That is a good thing to notice, but unfortunately not the problem i'm facing. I have the dropdown, but it won't deploy.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if you run Visual Studio in elevated mode. Could you try running it without elevation and the WP emulator should work as expected.

Comment: No luck. I had VSCommands starting me in elevated mode all the time. I changed that setting, disabled the extension, and created a new project but still get the same errors